# How to analyze heap profiler in chrome dev tool

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I got memory leaks issue on NodeJS application.
I tried many tutorials which guides to anlyze the heap snapshot.
In my case, I can find the constructor which has the most retained size, and it is the dedicated cause of leaks.
But what's next? Pointing to dedicated one, it lists in retaining path hundreds of object, which I can start to detect the cause of leaks.
Please help if you have any idea about that.
Below is the picture of snapshot in chrome dev tool

[image: PROFILER]

Comment: Can you list which tutorials you have read?

Comment: I read many, and also this https://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/, recommended by tons of users. I just do not know, with the list of the same object in that pictures, Where can I start to detect the leaks? :D

Comment: Every tutorials make a sample of leaky code then detect it by chrome dev tools. In their cases, We can easily watch the retained size of leaky class is allocated much of memories. In my case, Not any object has big memories occupation, my problem is my profile has tons of object with the same constructor WriteReq.